# Link .so library in android studio project

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, shared-libraries

As the title suggests I am trying to link a native `.so` to an android studio project. I have gone through the docs in android developer website and some more articles but unsuccessful in connecting the `.so` file with the project.

Whenever I try to run the code I get the following error

> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but
>   they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set
>   and tested correctly in the CMake files: testlib

Here is my CMake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

add_library(testlib SHARED IMPORTED)

set_property(TARGET testlib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "E:/project/Remote_Native/remote_attempt_1/app/libs/armeabi-v7a/libremotedesktop_client.so")

#find_path(testlib E:/project/Remote_Native/remote_attempt_1/app/libs/armeabi-v7a/RemoteDesktop.h)
find_library(testlib E:/project/Remote_Native/remote_attempt_1/app/libs/armeabi-v7a/libremotedesktop_client.so)

#add_library(remote SHARED IMPORTED)

#set_target_properties(remote PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libremotedesktop_client.so )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib}

                       ${testlib})

target_include_directories()
```

I have four `.so` files each for arm64, armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86. I have harcoded the armeabi-v7a lib in the path, android studio is throwing the above mentioned error when I do that. My actual aim is to dynamically load the library based on the chip in the phone. I am pretty sure that my current code is not achieving that.

Here are my queries

1. How to solve the error that I am getting? I have tried giving both relative and absolute path but to no avail I am getting the same error.
2. How do I add a `.so` and a `.h` file into a native android studio project? That has variations based on the chip on which the code is running?
3. When I directly add the `.h` file to the native folder I can reference the classes and functions in that header in my C code but I am unable to run the code. I have a `getInstance()` method in the `.h` file. Whenever I call the 
   `getInstance()` function it says `undefined refernce to getInstance()`. What I understand from that is the '.h' file is linked correctly but the definition of the function of the `.h` files which are actually present in the `.so` files are not linked. I believe this will be solved if question 1 and 2 are answered.
4. Is it necessary for all native android projects to have a .mk file? I didn't add one to my project and think it might be one of the cause for the error that I am getting.

Comment: "Here are my queries" - SO questions should be *one* question per post, not multiple.

Comment: @JesperJuhl . You are probably right and that rule applies if each of my query had a different answer. I believe I am making a rookie mistake in some line and that will clear all the 4 doubts I have, that is why I decided to put them all in a single question. If the answers for these queries seems to be different I will split them up into different questions later. Cheers :)

Comment: Have a look at this sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs  _"This sample uses the Android Studio CMake plugin with external library support. It demos how to: (*) 
include a pre-built static library (gmath) in your app; (*)
include a __pre-built shared library__ (gperf) in your app"_

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `find_library` in your case. For **log**, the library is resolved by NDK for you; for **libremotedesktop_client.so**, you know the exact path.

Here is the **CMakeLists.txt** that will work for you:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

add_library(remote SHARED IMPORTED)

set_property(TARGET remote PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "E:/project/Remote_Native/remote_attempt_1/app/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libremotedesktop_client.so")

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       log

                       remote)
```

Note that using full path (**E:/project…**) in CMake script is not the best practice; you probably can express the path to this library somehow relative to the path of your **CMakeLists.txt**, which is `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`.

Comment: Damn. Most CMake related answers are quite long. This one seems to be the shortest, that solved my problem. My situation is: CMake Version 3.10.2 so I don't have target_link_directories which seems to be a solution if you have Version > 3.10. Originally I wanted to link a library which I built in it's own module in Android Studio. The combination of add_library and set_property did the trick. Thank you

Comment: @hundolin they are now working on inter-module native dependencies in AS, via Prefab. See https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1559

Answer (score 3):

1-2). First of all, add `set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)` at the start of your CMakeLists.txt (just after `cmake_minimum_required(...)`) to allow another search paths for libraries. After this you can find lib just using standard `find_library`:

```
find_library(FOO_LIBRARY
         foo # Lib's full name in this case - libfoo.so
         PATHS path/to/lib/)
if (NOT FOO_LIBRARY)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Foo lib not found!")
endif()
```

You can use variable `ANDROID_ABI` to get particular library version, if directory with libraries organised in this way:

```
- path/to/lib
       - armeabi-v7a
           - libfoo.so
       - arm64-v8a
           - libfoo.so
       - x86
           - libfoo.so
       - x86_64
           - libfoo.so
```

So, search path in this case:`path/to/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/`

To include headers in project just use `include_directories`:

```
include_directories(path/to/headers)
```

4). .mk files only needed if you use `ndk-build` (so you don't need any)